# UITableView scrolls horizontally on iOS7 when loading Cell from Nib?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I created a `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
class RootTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  private let cellIdentifier = "MyCell2"
  private let cellNibName = "MyCell2"
  private var itemList: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<1000 {
      itemList.append("T\(i)")
    }

    let nib = UINib(nibName: cellNibName, bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemList.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell2

  return cell
}
```

`MyCell2` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`:

```
class MyCell2: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

MyCell2.xib contains a UIButton in its `ContentView`. The Identifier the UITableViewCell is set to `MyCell2` and the Class is set to `MyCell2`.

[image]

When I run the app on iOS8 everything works fine. There is no horizontal scrolling. When I run the app on iOS7 horizontal scrolling takes place:

[image]

**How can I prevent horizontal scrolling of the table in iOS7?**

**Edit:** My `UITableView` xib configuration is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this UITableView configuration in your xib file/storyboard?

[image]